# objc_msgSend for @selector(setOrientation:)

Tags: ios

In my app i am using objc_msgSend to change orientation of the whole device. In the app there are 2 buttons (Landscape and portrait). Whenever user clicks on Landscape then App should be in landscape.Similar for Portrait.

But this method doesn't change orientation every time. Sometime it works and sometime not.

Code is:-

```
- (void)updateOrientation
{
    NSInteger mode = -1;
    switch (appDel.orientationMode)
    {
        case 2:
        {
            UIDeviceOrientation orientation =  (UIDeviceOrientation)[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
            if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
                    orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
                    || orientation == 0)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {

                mode = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ;
            }
            else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
                mode = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            }
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
            UIDeviceOrientation orientation =  (UIDeviceOrientation)[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

            if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ||
                orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
                || orientation == 0)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

                mode = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ;
            }
            else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

                 mode = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ;
            }
        }
            break;
    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)] && (mode != -1))
    {
        objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using private API: (1) can be rejected by Apple; (2) may not work on all iOS versions; (3) is not guaranteed to work even if the selector is present. The best thing would be to redesign that manual rotation feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you change the orientation

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:YourDesiredOrientation];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```